# Getting Total Pages from XML Feed

Tags: php, xml

Hi I have a simple XML feed, which returns the data in the format shown below

```
  <Computers>
  <results totalPages="18" currentPage="18" totalResults="88"/>
  <computer id="1" name="IBM">
  <computertype id="1" name="Windows"/>
  </computer>
  <computer id="94" name="Acer">
  <computertype id="1" name="windows"/>
  </computer>
  <computer id="1533" name="selfbuild">
  <computertype id="1" name="windows"/>
  </computer>
  </computers>
```

to display the results i use the following

```
foreach($xml->computer as $computer){
 echo $computer['name'];
```

What i am trying to do is get the result of the total pages, current page and total results in to variables, the problem i have is that when i try and write them as below, it isn't returning a result.

```
 echo $results['totalPages'];
```

I think it is because the foreach is starting after the results section, but if i try and write them as below,  again i get nothing.

```
   foreach($xml->results as $results){
  echo $results['totalPages'];
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the attributes of a node.

Do it like this, using SimpleXML:

```
$xml = <<<XML
  <Computers>
  <results totalPages="18" currentPage="18" totalResults="88"/>
  <computer id="1" name="IBM">
  <computertype id="1" name="Windows"/>
  </computer>
  <computer id="94" name="Acer">
  <computertype id="1" name="windows"/>
  </computer>
  <computer id="1533" name="selfbuild">
  <computertype id="1" name="windows"/>
  </computer>
  </Computers>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml->results->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"<br>";
}
```

Which outputs the following:

> totalPages="18"
>  currentPage="18"
>  totalResults="88"

Or access each attribute directly:

```
echo $xml->results->attributes()->totalPages;
```